# get maximal top k values

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, optimization, computer-science

Now I have an expression `y=0.5*a+0.7*b+0.4*c`, where `0<a,b,c<1`. Suppose there is a list table for the values of `a,b,c`, for example:

```
(a,   b,   c)
---------------
(0.9, 0.4, 0.6)
(0.5, 0.8, 0.4)
(0.7, 0.4, 0.8)
(0.9, 0.2, 0.1)
...
```

Are there some fast ways of finding the top `k=3` values for `y`?

I know that the brute-force way is to enumerate every tuples of `(a,b,c)` for computing `y`, and then find the k largest values for y, but when the number of tuples are huge, it seems that this method is not very efficient. So any other ways are welcome!

Comment: Is there anything known about the tuples? Otherwise, you would need to look at the the tuples, so we cannot do better than "brute force".

Comment: Is the ordering of the tuples in the table under your control?

Comment: No. The ordering is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walk over every tuple. As you read it in, evaluate the expression on it, and maintain an array of the top 3 values as you go.

The problem with trying to be cleverer than that is that if your list of tuples is huge, the time your program spends is going to be completely dominated by just reading it, and no cleverness can get you out of that. The overhead of evaluating your expression and keeping an array up to date with the top three values will be completely trivial, just a few instructions on top of the reading part.

(As to why I suggest keeping your top values in an array rather than something fancier like a heap: when k=3, the constant overhead of anything that uses a nontrivial number of instructions to execute, or that requires enough memory that you're not always going to get a cache hit, is going to outweigh any asymptotic benefit the data structure provides.)

Comment: +1, but a heap can also be implemented as an array, and that is the implementation normally chosen when k is known (and k is somewhat larger).

Answer (score 2):

Using QuickSelect would give you an O(n) complexity on average:

1. Assuming there are N elements and y=f(a,b,c), calculate an array Y of length N for each of (a,b,c) (add an index to (a,b,c) to Y as well for the back reference you'll need later).
2. Use QuickSelect on Y to get the (N-k)th order statistic, and obtain the resultant Y. The elements Y[N-k-1] to Y[N-1] will be your k largest elements.
3. Sort Y[N-k-1] to Y[N-1] to obtain your result.

Comment: For k=3 this is overkill. The space usage is Omega(n), when we can do in O(1). Of course for larger k, this might be applicable.

Comment: @Knoothe Yes I was generalizing k. I agree that for small values of k, jacobm's solution would work well enough with it's low space requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You're still going to have to go through each tuple in the table regardless of what you do, so this is going to be at least an `O(n)` operation. For only the top 3 values, you can hardcode an array of size 3 and the `if` checks required.

So, given that you will have to go through the entire table at least once, you will not do any better than `O(n)` in this situation.